# Is there any way to get the Distribution Group name of a NewEmail Event in Outlook VBA?

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to divert new emails in Outlook from a distribution group called Customer Service to a subfolder during a certain time. I don't think rules have the capability to divert emails at a certain time so I'm using Application.NewEmail Event.

I have my code set up right now so that it could divert emails from an Exchange sender's email address to a subfolder. However, I need to somehow be able to do the same thing with a Distribution Group and I'm not sure how to extract the information necessary to identify a distribution group.

Here's my code:

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
  Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
  Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
  Set olApp = Outlook.Application
  Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  Set Items = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal cusItem As Object)
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Items = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
    Dim strAddress As String, strEntryId As String
    Dim objAddressentry As Outlook.AddressEntry, objExchangeUser As Outlook.ExchangeUser
    Dim objReply As Outlook.MailItem, objRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim objDestFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    If TypeName(cusItem) = "MailItem" And cusItem.SenderEmailType = "EX" Then

        On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

        Set objReply = cusItem.Reply()
        Set objRecipient = objReply.Recipients.Item(1)

        strEntryId = objRecipient.EntryID

        objReply.Close OlInspectorClose.olDiscard

        Set objAddressentry = objNS.GetAddressEntryFromID(strEntryId)
        Set objExchangeUser = objAddressentry.GetExchangeUser()

        strAddress = objExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress()

        If strAddress = "jabach@example.com" And TimeValue(Now()) >= TimeValue("08:00:00 AM") And TimeValue(Now()) <= TimeValue("05:00:00 PM") Then

        Set objDestFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("ryule")

        cusItem.Move objDestFolder

        End If

    End If

ProgramExit:
  Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
  MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description & vbCrLf & "Click Ok to continue"
  Resume ProgramExit

End Sub
```

There's also some issues with Application_Startup() not actually firing up Outlook which is why I have all those variables declared twice.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check out the [AddressEntry.AddressEntryUserType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.addressentry.addressentryusertype) property which returns a constant from the [OlAddressEntryUserType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.oladdressentryusertype) enumeration representing the user type of the [AddressEntry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.addressentry). `AddressEntryUserType` provides a level of granularity for user types that is finer than that of `AddressEntry.DisplayType`. The `DisplayType` property does not distinguish users with different types of `AddressEntry`, such as an `AddressEntry` that has a Simple Mail Transfer Protocol (SMTP) email address, a Lightweight Directory Access Protocol (LDAP) address, an Exchange user address, or an `AddressEntry` in the Outlook Contacts Address Book. All these entires have `olUser` as their `AddressEntry.DisplayType`. For example:

```
Sub DemoAE() 
 Dim colAL As Outlook.AddressLists  
 Dim oAL As Outlook.AddressList  
 Dim colAE As Outlook.AddressEntries  
 Dim oAE As Outlook.AddressEntry  
 Dim oExUser As Outlook.ExchangeUser  
 Set colAL = Application.Session.AddressLists  
 For Each oAL In colAL  
 'Address list is an Exchange Global Address List  
  If oAL.AddressListType = olExchangeGlobalAddressList Then  
   Set colAE = oAL.AddressEntries  
   For Each oAE In colAE  
     If oAE.AddressEntryUserType = _  
       olExchangeUserAddressEntry Then  
       Set oExUser = oAE.GetExchangeUser  
       Debug.Print(oExUser.JobTitle)  
       Debug.Print(oExUser.OfficeLocation)  
       Debug.Print(oExUser.BusinessTelephoneNumber)  
     End If  
   Next  
  End If  
 Next  
End Sub
```

So, you may need to use the [AddressEntry.GetExchangeDistributionList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.addressentry.getexchangedistributionlist) method in case of Exchange distribution lists.

The [OlAddressEntryUserType enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.oladdressentryusertype) provides the following constants:

- olExchangeAgentAddressEntry -    An address entry that is an Exchange agent.
- olExchangeDistributionListAddressEntry -     An address entry that is an Exchange distribution list.
- olExchangeOrganizationAddressEntry - An address entry that is an Exchange organization.
- olExchangePublicFolderAddressEntry - An address entry that is an Exchange public folder.
- olExchangeRemoteUserAddressEntry - An Exchange user that belongs to a different Exchange forest.
- olExchangeUserAddressEntry - An Exchange user that belongs to the same Exchange forest.
- olLdapAddressEntry - An address entry that uses the Lightweight Directory Access Protocol (LDAP).
- olOtherAddressEntry -    A custom or some other type of address entry such as FAX.
- olOutlookContactAddressEntry -   An address entry in an Outlook Contacts folder.
- olOutlookDistributionListAddressEntry -  An address entry that is an Outlook distribution list.
- olSmtpAddressEntry - An address entry that uses the Simple Mail Transfer Protocol (SMTP).

Finally, I'd suggest handling the [NewMailEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.Application.NewMailEx) event of the Application class. The NewMailEx event fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. You can use the Entry ID returned in the EntryIDCollection array to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method and process the item.

Comment: Is there a way to get the display name or alias of the sender?

Comment: See [ExchangeUser.Alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.exchangeuser.alias) and [ExchangeUser.Name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.exchangeuser.name) properties.

Comment: The [ExchangeDistributionList.GetExchangeDistributionListMembers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.exchangedistributionlist.getexchangedistributionlistmembers) returns an `AddressEntries` collection that represents the members of the Exchange distribution list.